# Trace path of Java Path2D

Tags: java, plot, apache-commons, bezier, spline

I have a program that makes a lot of use of Path2D.Double for drawing curves. I now want to be able to get each individual point on the curve. I'm having trouble finding a function or class that I can feed the values I can get from the Path2D.Double class (Control points and end points) and allow me to travel along the line.

I want to continue to use Path2D for storage and drawing purposes since it's used all over my program, however when I need to travel along the path, I want to be able to get all the points along it.

I was looking at the splineInterpolator from the apache commons:
https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.6/org/apache/commons/math3/analysis/interpolation/SplineInterpolator.html

If I'm reading everything right, it's looking like I would have to give the Control and End points to the splineInteropolator, get a PolynomialSplineFunction (which is a set of Polynomial functions) from that, and then from that set, go through each and iterate using PolynomialFunction.value(x).

But how do I know the range for each polynomial function? The PolynomialSplineFunction only lets me use isValidPoint for the entire Interpolation range, not just that of each spline segment.

Am I on the right track? Or is there a simpler way to do this?

This is my first question on StackOverflow. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Sorry, which Curve2D (it's not a unique name, which package are you pulling it from)? Also, what does "each individual point on the curve" mean? A curve has an inifnite number of points, so you seem to be thinking of something else, but forgot to mention some details.

Comment: Sorry I meant Path2D.Double. I fixed it in the question. Specifically I use Path2D from here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Path2D.Double.html. I place the starting point using moveTo(), and then complete the curve by using curveTo().

I just want to be able to get the points that are, or would be, rendered to the screen.

Comment: `curveto` just forms a cubic Bezier curve, so computing any point on that curve should be pretty easy, there's a million pages on the internet that teach you how to build a curve LUT, including my own page (https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo)

Comment: Would [FlatteningPathIterator](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/geom/FlatteningPathIterator.html) be of use?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans i looked at your book and it's an amazing resource for reference, and if i end up having to implement the Curves myself. thank you!

Comment: @WJS that might be exactly what i'm looking for actually. Also while looking at this I saw that if you start with a CubicCurve2D as the base instead of a Path2D as the base, CubicCurve2D has a "subdivide" function that might come in useful. Hopefully the FlatteningPathIterator works as i'm thinking it will, as that seems like the best option. will work on it tonight. thanks for your help!